# How can I clean up a failed installation of Visual Studio 11?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I tried to install Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview on `D:\Programs\VS11`, and the installation failed due to low disk space on `C:` drive (which I solved after the error). When I try to uninstall VS11 I get this error:

[image]

I had to delete the some folders on disk, some registry entries related to VS11 (wild guesses, of course), and use msizap to remove the MSI's. After all these steps I managed to start the installation, but I get some script errors, so in order to uninstall and retry the setup I have to repeat the cleanup process.

Is there some clean up tool like it was for VS2008, or some blog that highlights everything that must be removed for a successful reinstallation?

**UPDATE**

On my way to a Win 7 reinstallation, I managed to get another error:

[image]

```
Applying package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2057AF3-1C3B-3DC5-8C6B-56013B5299B4}v11.0.40825\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' IGNOREDEPENDENCIES="{a3c0442e-f8f7-4089-ac77-1e0c50901f63}" NOVSUI="1"'
MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vcRuntimeMinimum_x64) failed: Error: 1402 ErrorMessage: Error 1402.Could not open key: UNKNOWN\Components\E66957AD6A10C4743836CB3CB4576BE1\3FA7502AB3C15CD3C8B66510B325994B.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

This one was solved with the steps from here: [How to fix 'Error 1402. Could not open key: UNKNOWN...'](http://www.okino.com/conv/changing_windows_registry_permissions.htm)

Comment: It's better to use virtual machine for buggy early preview versions.

Comment: @Alex: true, I learned it the hard way :D but my PC is slow enough to exclude VMs from my options.

Comment: Here's instructions for VS2010.  Wouldn't be surprised if a lot of it still applies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw(VS.100).aspx#uninstalling (I'm going through this right now too, for both 2010 and the CTP, due to my machine breaking and causing explorer to crash whenever I see a `.sln` in explorer.  Not sure if this is the CTP version's fault tho as it was on my box for a while before I experienced this issue, and I had a sudden blue screen and chkdsk last night while I was off eating dinner =P - rant over!)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: step 2 is: Remove all instances of Visual Studio 2010 products, which is exactly what it's not working for me.

Comment: @alexandrul: The (un)install logs might contain more info than you're seeing in the UI.  Clearing the temp dir might help with some of this, as might redownloading the install files and repairing the install before trying to remove it.  My uninstall kept giving me errors, but I've been able to remove piece by piece, by removing dependencies that were blocking other piece's uninstall (dependencies which I only found out about half way through with it asking for the disk - the path of which I supplied, yet it was not accepting).  Sorry man, that's all I've got right now :)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: first, thank you for your help. Second, after 2 days I blessed MS and reinstalled the OS. Everything was ok on a clean install of Win 7.

Comment: @alexandrul: YW, for what it's worth.  Sometimes slash and burn is the only way to go.  At least you have a clean box now :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the installer is not corrupt(I assume you are installing it from the iso)? Did you verify the SHA1 and CRC? If you were dealing with space issues, this could be a reason.

Comment: Installer is not corrupt (worked like a charm after an OS reinstall), and space issues were solved before trying to uninstall.